# xubuntu: stopped working during system update

Tags: updates, xubuntu, update-manager

I updated my xubuntu and after some time, screen became black.

Moving mouse, pressing keyboard keys don't work so I restarted my laptop.

Then I got the following error and cannot boot up.

[image: error]

Please help

Comment: At the very top of your screen it indicates unable to mount root fs. My best guess with the limited information you have provided is a failed or failing hard disk.

Comment: No Problem. @MayMyatnoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted and chose the old/previous version to boot up.

Then I ran the following command.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```